# If..then statement in mysql

Tags: mysql, if-statement, stored-procedures

I have stored procedure with one parameter called paramType (INT)

I'm wondering is there any way how to implement next situation in mysql:

```
BEGIN
SELECT Code, Price, Type  FROM table
IF paramType IS NOT NULL THEN
WHERE Type = paramType
ELSE
SELECT Code, Price Type  FROM table
END;
```

So, if paramType is null (empty) then just execute `SELECT Code, Price, Type  FROM table` but if paramType contains value than execute query with condition like:

```
SELECT Code, Price Type  FROM table WHERE Type = paramType
```

Or is there other solution without if/then/else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the more elegant way of writing this :

```
SELECT Code, Price, Type 
FROM table
WHERE paramType IS NULL OR Type = paramType
```

Comment: it should use AND operator?

Comment: Think about it.. @YeWin

Comment: because of OR operator Type=paramType will always do

Comment: That's the point, if its `NULL` , all records should be returned, else -> `Type = paramType` @YeWin .

Comment: you are right, if it's null, all records will be returned, +1 ,